# From Hijiri date to Gregorian in java

Tags: java, user-interface, datetime

I have a GUI that have two comboxes and one textfield to enter the user's Hijiri birth date. I want to convert that Hijiri date to a Gregorian one ... every solution I found either a complex one or does not work .. I even checked the Joda-Time - API - Islamic calendar(HijrahChronology) and it does not have any converting methods !!

Comment: https://ibb.co/cNmPa6

Comment: There is a [Hijrah chronology](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/chrono/class-use/HijrahChronology.html) built into Java 8 and Java 9. The Joda-Time project is in maintenance mode, advising migration to the java.time classes.

Comment: do java time classes have converting methods for hijiri dates?

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.from(                     // Convert from Hijrah chronology to ISO 8601 chronology.
    HijrahDate.of( 1400 , 2 , 19 )  // Instantiate a recent birthdate using Islamic calendar.
).toString()                        // Generate text representing this ISO date.
```

> 1980-01-08

## Details

The [`java.time.chrono`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/package-summary.html) package offers a [Hijrah chronology](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/HijrahChronology.html), as well as other chronologies.

While I know *nothing* about the [Islamic calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_calendar), it appears to me you can easily convert between [ISO 8601 chronology](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/IsoChronology.html) to that Hijrah chronology.

Instantiate in Hijrah chronology.

```
// Instantiate a recent birth date using Islamic calendar.
HijrahDate hd = HijrahDate.of( 1400 , 2 , 19 );
System.out.println( "hd.toString(): " + hd );
```

> hd.toString(): Hijrah-umalqura AH 1400-02-19

Convert to ISO 8601 chronology.

```
// Convert from Hijrah chronology to ISO 8601 chronology.
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.from( hd );
System.out.println( "ld.toString(): " + ld );
```

> ld.toString(): 1980-01-08